# 10 ( different ) people have the option of traveling to 20 ( different > ) destination with restrictions.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, inclusion-exclusion, balls-in-bins

> 10 ( different ) people have the option of traveling to 20 ( different
>   ) destination . On how many ways they can leave if we know that one
>   can visit more destination ( the order of visits is not important
>   ) , no one will visit more than three destinations , and that some
>   people may give up the trip ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So each person visits $0$ to $3$ destinations? And are all destinations visited? Any by "on how many ways they can leave", do you mean in how many ways can their destinations be chosen?

Comment: 20 different locations, in how many ways they can visit them.yes, and yes how many destination be chosen,  sorry for bad english, i am from croatia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, I interpret the question to be asking in how many different ways $20$ destinations can be assigned to $10$ people such that no person is assigned more than $3$ destinations. This is a case of [balls in bins with limited capacity](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath337/kmath337.htm), which can be solved using [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), and the answer is

$$
\sum_{t=0}^{10}(-1)^t\binom{10}t\binom{10+20-4t-1}{10-1}=\sum_{t=0}^{10}(-1)^t\binom{10}t\binom{29-4t}{9}=44803
$$

(where, contrary to the standard convention, the binomial coefficients are taken to vanish when the upper argument is negative).

Comment: In case the restriction that each destination is visited by one traveller wasn't intended, the answer is simply $\left(\binom{20}0+\binom{20}1+\binom{20}2+\binom{20}3\right)^{10}$, since in that case all $10$ travellers can choose destinations independently.